# Why laravel eloquent model does not have an id after it is saved?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an account model. I define & save it following way:

```
$account = new Account();
$account->email = $request->get('email');
$account->name  = $request->get('name');
$account->save();

dd($account->id) // null
```

Why account id is not updated? I use autoincremental id field.
I see record in the database.

Comment: Works fine on my Laravel install. Is your auto-increment ID field named `id` or something else?

Comment: You must have set `incrementing` to `false`. Otherwise, you're just doing something wrong.

Comment: Include your migration table class in the question.

Comment: @ceejayoz it is called id. @jarek-tkaczyk i can't see any `incrementing=false` definitions, either in model or in migration.

Comment: @marcanuy i see only `$table->increments('id')` definition, related to the identifier in the migration.

Comment: Please add your schema to the question.

Comment: Had the same problem. turns out I overloaded the save() method in my model so it could not save the item under certain circumstances. Default save() method of laravel eloquent models works fine

Comment: Had the same problem. turns out I overloaded the save() method in my model so it could not save the item under certain circumstances. Default save() method of laravel eloquent models works fine

Comment: In your Account model add the following:

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    protected $fillable = ["name", "email"];

Answer (score 5):

If your `Account` model is extending `Pivot` instead of `Model` (being a pivot model), it doesn't use an auto-incrementing `id` by default. In that case, you probably have two choices.

Explicitly set your auto-increment primary key:

```php
class Account extends Pivot {
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    public $incrementing = true;

    // -- snip --
}
```

Or you can convert your model to extend `Model` instead:

```php
class Account extends Model {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set your primary key on your model.

Try to insert this on your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = "id";
```

Comment: This is the default when extending `Model`, and doesn't have to be set explicitly.